# How to filter in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba, filter, win32com

I am trying to automate a macro-enabled Excel workbook process using Python. I would like to use `win32com` if possible but am open to switching to other libraries if needed.

Once I get the workbook open and on the sheet I need, there is data already there with auto-filters applied. I just need to filter on a column to make the data available to the macro when I run it.

I use `wb.RefreshAll()` to import the data from existing connections. Eventually I will need to pass a value entered by the user to the filter as it will be different each time the automation runs.

Most solutions involve copying select data to a Pandas DataFrame etc. but I need the filtered data to remain in the sheet so it can be used by the macro.

Comment: better you put some example with the excel sheet and it's easy anyone to understand better your question

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a Python script to automate Macros. Basically, the idea was to batch-edit a collection of .doc files and have a macro run for all of them, without having to open them one by one.

First:
What is this macro you want to run? 
Second: 
What is the data that you need to make visible, and what do you mean by that?

To get you started, try this:

```
data = [{"test1": 1, "test2": 2}, {"test1": 3, "test2": 4}]

import win32com.client as win32
def openExcel():

    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
    #wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
    ws = wb.Sheets(1) #The worksheet you want to edit later
    xl.Visible = True

    return ws

def print2Excel(datapoint:dict, ws):
    print(datapoint)

    const = win32.constants #.Insert()-Methods keywargs are packaged into const.
    ws.Range("A1:B1").Insert(const.xlShiftDown, const.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow)
    ws.Cells(1,1).Value = datapoint["test1"]
    ws.Cells(1,2).Value = datapoint["test2"]

ws = openExcel() #<- When using Open(filepath), pass the whole filepath, starting at C:\ or whatever drive.
for datapoint in data:
    print2Excel(datapoint, ws)
```

This showcases some of the basics on how to work with Excel objects in win32com

Comment: I ended up just writing a macro that uses the parameters passed from python and filters. Thank you!